# Access IF statement how to get hours from EndDate-StartDate

Tags: ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

Need some help with Access IF Statement
So I have End Date and Start Date
How do I know the number of hours occurred within the end date and start date? 
So I want EndDate-StartDate= INT value

For example, 
EndDate is 2017/03/16 13:00
StartDate is 2017/03/16 15:00

So enddate-startdate = -2
Thank you

Comment: Have a look at DateDiff.

Comment: @Fionnuala I did use
DateDiff(Hour, endDate, StartDate) but everytime I try to run I got parameter Run

Comment: Datediff is h not hour https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/DateDiff-Function-e6dd7ee6-3d01-4531-905c-e24fc238f85f and it is a string.

Comment: @Fionnuala yeah, I use Hour but everytime I run it keep popping the 'Enter Parameter Value thing'

Comment: Please post the sql or the vba.

Answer (score 0):

Use *DateDiff* with "h":

```
Select *, DateDiff("h", [StartDate], [EndDate]) As Hours
From YourTable
```

Will return 2 hours for your example dates.